# Shared Layers, Different Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two Keras models (functional API) sharing some layers. I m wondering if I train the first model, will the second one get its shared layers' weights updated automatically or should I load the weights manually.

I know from the [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) that layers could be shared within the same model but I don't have any clue for this particular situation.

I am also wondering whether Keras models with shared layers are sharing the same computational graph or they have independent ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you train the first model, the weights from the shared layers will be updated automatically in every other model. Consider the following example:

```
x = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
encoder = Dense(output_dim)(x)
decoder = Dense(input_dim)(encoder)

autoencoder = Model(input=x, output=decoder)
supervised = Model(input=x, output=encoder)

autoencoder.compile(...)
supervised.compile(...)
```

Here, when you train `supervised`, the weights from layer `encoder` are updated both for `supervised` and `autoencoder`. In other words, the weights from `encoder` belong exclusively to this layer, and they don't depend on the models that use this layer.

For your second question, the answer is that Keras uses only one computational graph (even when the models don't share layers).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.